# Обрезать строку после определенного слова,но не вырезать другие такие же слова

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток,имеется строка : "Привет,это я и я сейчас уйду".
Необходимо обрезать текст после первой буквы "я" (и её тоже вырезать),чтобы получилась строка "и я сейчас уйду.".
Пробовал так:

```
$result = explode("я ", $text);
echo $result[1];
```

Но он вырезает не только первую букву "я",но и последующие.
Заранее благодарен! :)

Comment: сделайте explode с 3 параметром limit. $result = explode('я ', $text, 2);

Comment: Про регулярные выражения не слышали?

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Используйте третий параметр функции `explode()` — `$limit`.

```
$result = explode('я', $text, 2);
echo ltrim($result[1]);
```

Comment: Круто,спасибо большое!

Comment: @uan'ka отметьте ответ правильным

Answer (score 4):

**Без массивов**
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strstr.php

```
$string = "Привет,это я и я сейчас уйду";
echo trim(strstr($string, 'я'), 'я ');
```

Answer (score 3):

ещё как вариант но с explode лучше выглядит

```
<?php
$string = "Привет,это я и я сейчас уйду";
$string = substr($string,strpos($string, 'я')+2);
echo $string;
```